# Spring force for physical push buttons

Tags: buttons, physical, ergonomics, human-factors-engineering

Are there any design guides or existing studies that provide recommendations for the spring force (e.g. initial force [lb, kg] and force increase [lb/in, kg/mm]) of a physical momentary push button that provides comfortable use but also a "well-built" feel (for an adult with normal finger function)?

The buttons I have in mind would be about the size of a finger tip, and directly control quick-release mechanical latching clips (so you'd press, then probably hold for ~1 second while manipulating the device), with about 3.5mm travel. They're printed parts, and I need to find some springs to put behind them but there's a huge range of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you look into ergonomic standards and tables and find the one that fits your use case the best. For example, this is from [Cummins Corp](https://public.cummins.com/sites/CSP/SiteCollectionDocuments/StandardsandProcesses/CORP-09-10-03-01%20Ergonomics%20Standard.pdf)

[image]

But other sources say that the recommended force shouldn't exceed 3 lbs ([Ergoweb](https://ergoweb.com/force-guidelines/))

[image]

Or even [2 lbs](https://ergoweb.com/controls-and-activation-buttons/#:%7E:text=Button%20push%20force,(1%20kg).) (same site, different context).

Comment: Oh amazing, thank you so much for this; and for some good search keywords. I knew it was out there somewhere.